# Do schools in the USA accept a Student for Grade 12 when he's completed his A1 level (Grade 11 in the UK)?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, student-visa, education, san-francisco

My family is planning to move to San Francisco and I was just wondering if I'd be accepted into Grade 12 there, after having completed Grade 11(A1 Levels) from the British Council or will I have to start over from Grade 11 in the US?

Comment: Why do you think you'd have to start over in Grade 11?  Is this based on your age or different grading system?

Comment: How old will you be this autumn? From what I see online, there's a possibility that your Grade 11 equates to a US grade 10 (by age), so you might be required to do Grade 11. However, if you've been doing well in classes and/or taking classes that equate to US grade 11, you might be able to "skip" a grade in the US.

Comment: I'm 17 and my B-day is on 25th Dec, I'm a B student, so, are the A1 levels equal to 11th Grade in the US?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grade level placement will very much depend on what you have studied. In seeking admission to a US school, you'll present all of your school records. Those will be evaluated against what is required for US graduation with a standard diploma, you'll be given credit for subjects you've taken successfully in England, and you'll be placed accordingly, not in a grade that coincides with your age.

In California, here's a overview of the minimum set of courses required for high school graduation. And keep in mind that these are the basics; you'll be given credit for coursework which exceeds them.

**[California Department of Education State Minimum Course Requirements](http://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/gs/hs/hsgrmin.asp)**

> EC 51225.3 states that all pupils receiving a diploma of graduation from a California high school must have completed all of the following courses, while in grades nine to twelve, inclusive:
>
> Unless otherwise specified, each course shall have a duration of one school year:
>
> - Three courses in English
> - Two courses in mathematics, including one year of Algebra I (EC Section 51224.5)
> - Two courses in science, including biological and physical sciences
> - Three courses in social studies, including United States history and geography; world history, culture, and geography; a one-semester course in American government and civics, and a one-semester course in economics
> - One course in visual or performing arts,  foreign language, or commencing with the 2012-13 school year, career technical education. For the purpose of satisfying the minimum course requirement, a course in American Sign Language shall be deemed a course in foreign language
> - Two courses in physical education, unless the pupil has been exempted pursuant to the provisions of EC Section 51241

Where you may fall short are in those pertaining to the US (history, geography, government/civics), but it is not unusual for transfer students to take all such classes concurrently; they do not need to be taken consecutively.

Make sure you bring with you a full and official transcript of your school records, showing subjects taken, grades and Grade Point Average (GPA), and, as appropriate, GCSE results.